# Network tcp parameters

Tags: networking, tcp

i have a `netstat -s` output which i would like some opinions on. Which are the parameters that seems to appear to have problems? from what I can see, `tcpInUnorderBytes` and `tcpInUnorderSegs` have some values, which indicates the network might have problems? Also, `tcpRTTNoupdate`. Any others that i must look out for , in order to detect network problems? thanks

```
TCP     tcpRtoAlgorithm     =     4     tcpRtoMin           =   400
    tcpRtoMax           = 60000     tcpMaxConn          =    -1
    tcpActiveOpens      =804940     tcpPassiveOpens     =102075
    tcpAttemptFails     =700896     tcpEstabResets      = 59183
    tcpCurrEstab        =    51     tcpOutSegs          =2093089847
    tcpOutDataSegs      =2020287084 tcpOutDataBytes     =3905751072
    tcpRetransSegs      =1490137    tcpRetransBytes     =2098953445
    tcpOutAck           =7179623    tcpOutAckDelayed    =6107245
    tcpOutUrg           =     2     tcpOutWinUpdate     =    64
    tcpOutWinProbe      =   276     tcpOutControl       =1829500
    tcpOutRsts          =757145     tcpOutFastRetrans   =     0
    tcpInSegs           =2040038050
    tcpInAckSegs        =2019368757 tcpInAckBytes       =1902820181
    tcpInDupAck         =5828005    tcpInAckUnsent      =     0
    tcpInInorderSegs    =1967170566 tcpInInorderBytes   =3411672873
    tcpInUnorderSegs    =   176     tcpInUnorderBytes   = 22045
    tcpInDupSegs        =  1269     tcpInDupBytes       = 51603
    tcpInPartDupSegs    =     1     tcpInPartDupBytes   =   884
    tcpInPastWinSegs    =     0     tcpInPastWinBytes   =     0
    tcpInWinProbe       =     0     tcpInWinUpdate      =    20
    tcpInClosed         = 54627     tcpRttNoUpdate      =54460094
    tcpRttUpdate        =1964766727 tcpTimRetrans       = 57093
    tcpTimRetransDrop   =    47     tcpTimKeepalive     =  1441
    tcpTimKeepaliveProbe=   510     tcpTimKeepaliveDrop =    46
    tcpListenDrop       =     0     tcpListenDropQ0     =     0
    tcpHalfOpenDrop     =     0     tcpOutSackRetrans   =1160084
```

Comment: Are you experiencing an actual problem, or are you hoping to script something that would interrogate this values to alert for a problem?  TCP is a fault tolerant protocol, and out-of-sequencing and retransmits are expected.

Comment: hi, thanks. I have slow connection issue and was wondering if i could detect something from these output. my tcp_conn_req_max_q value is 128. I guess this is not recommended?

Comment: Hi Dorothy, to get the best out of SU, it pays to begin with the detail of the problem you are trying to solve, then include what you have done to try and solve it so far.  That way, we can offer different avenues to solve the problem if the one currently taken isn't likely to help. This would include the type of connection you are using, and the type of slow down you are experiencing.